# How do i use if/else statement inside a child in flutter?

Tags: flutter, if-statement, dart, flutter-layout, screen-orientation

#### I want to use if/else statement

So that i can have **MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly** for column only if the **orientation is landscape**. So, it doesn't change my layout in portrait orientation.

#### Here's the code

```
class _MobileLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  const _MobileLayout({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var orientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
    return Container(
      width: orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 250 : 100,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            blurRadius: 16,
            color: Colors.black12,
          )
        ],
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: AppDrawer.getDrawerOptions(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

***I've tried it multiple ways around***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the default value is `MainAxisAlignment mainAxisAlignment = MainAxisAlignment.start,`, therefore you can do as below;

```
child: Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: orientation == Orientation.landscape? 
      MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly : MainAxisAlignment.start, 
  children: AppDrawer.getDrawerOptions(),
),
```

which will also use the default value for `portrait`